# "Rainbow" header on web and mobile

Tags: website-design, color

I've seen a design pattern pop up now and again on the web and mobile apps. It's a "rainbow" pattern across the top about 5 pixels high.

For a great example, check out gowalla.com.

Anyone have any idea what this is useful for or what type of effect they're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a design pattern. It's just something some people use as a color accent, I don't think there's a hidden agenda or anything by it. It's just something -- an entity, part of the design, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's merely a visual separator. Probably multi-colored to help promote a sense of fun. There's no technical use for it and if you see it repeated, its merely because it's becoming "trendy".